# How to make find -name to return error if no file found

Tags: linux, unix, command, find, execvp

I have tried really hard but could not figure out a way to print an error if

`find -name \"filename"`

does not find any file.  The code I am using so far is as follows:

```
    char *argv[];
       argv[0]="find";
       argv[1]="-name";
       argv[2]=strcat(str,"\abc.txt"); 
       argv[3]=NULL;
       pid_t pid;
       pid= fork();

   if(pid==0)
   {
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
   printf("file does not exist");
    }
```

But I can't print my print statement because `find -name \"filename"` never returns an error.

Comment: You'll have to inspect the output from `find`, e.g. by using a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell condition, such as:

```
[ "$(find /opt -name '*.txt')" ] && echo Found || echo Not found
```

which is basically the same as:

```
[ "$(find /opt -name '*.txt')" '!=' '' ] && echo Found || echo Not found
```

If you're using GNU find, try using `-quit`.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to this question, but I just found an elegant answer :-)

```
find . -type d -empty -and -not -name . -print -exec rmdir {} + | \
  awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) {exit(1)}}'
```

`find` here looks for empty directories in the current directory,
removes the empty directories,
prints the name of removed directories to the pipe,
`awk` prints the output of `find` and if no output is found `NR == 0`, bails out with an error code.

This means I can now iteratively remove empty directories:

```
while find . -type d -empty -and -not -name . -print -exec rmdir {} + | \
  awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) {exit(1)}}'; \
do echo; done
```

Replace "my" `find` parameters with yours, keep the `awk` part either as is or without the `{print}` if you do not want to see the output of `find` in the terminal, and "voilà".

Answer (score -2):

try to using:

```
find -f PATTERN
```

after used this construction, you have a result code by:

```
echo $?
```

if PATTERN was not exists, this result code must be 1 (or not equals zero in some cases)

Comment: "find -f" errors out with: "find: unknown predicate `-f'"